# Fill data in a webforms and get names of the party

Tags: python, excel, mechanize

There is a website: [Tin number search](http://mahavat.gov.in/Tin_Search/Tinsearch.jsp). I have an excel sheet full of TIN numbers(Sales Tax number) which I have to fill in TIN number part and fill the name back to the sheet is there anyway I can automate this as I tried to use mechanize but it responds with blank replies. Some example(Valid) TIN number for code testing are:

27200599589V
27940018928V
27901053455V

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
Sub Utility()
    Dim objIE As Object, htmldoc As Object, data, i As Long, lrow As Long
    Dim TinNo As String
    Cells(1, 2).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    lrow = Selection.Count
    For i = 1 To lrow
        Cells(i, 2) = cleartext(Cells(i, 2).Value)
        On Error Resume Next
    Next

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With objIE

        .Navigate "http://mahavat.gov.in/Tin_Search/Tinsearch.jsp"

        Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Set TIN = .document.getelementsbyname("tin")
        Set htmldoc = CreateObject("HTMLfile")

        'data = Range("B1:G" & lrow)

        On Error Resume Next

        For i = 1 To lrow

            Set TIN = .document.getelementsbyname("tin")

            Cells(i, 2).Select
            If Not IsError(Cells(i, 2)) Then
                TIN.Item(0).Value = Cells(i, 2)

                .document.getElementById("Submit").Click

                Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

                htmldoc.body.innerhtml = objIE.document.body.innerhtml

                temp = Trim(Split(htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("Table")(14).innertext, Cells(i, 2))(1))

                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    .Navigate "http://mahavat.gov.in/Tin_Search/Tinsearch.jsp"
                    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
                    Err.Clear
                    Cells(i, 3) = "Invelid TIN(Shl'd Start with 27,Totl 12 Chr)"
                    Cells(i, 4) = "Invelid TIN"
                Else
                    Cells(i, 3) = Mid(temp, InStrRev(temp, " ") + 1, Len(temp))
                    Cells(i, 4) = Trim(Split(temp, Cells(i, 3))(0))
                End If
            End If
       Next

    End With
End Sub
Function cleartext(inputstring As String) As String
    Dim onlynumbers As String
    onlynumbers = OnlyNums(inputstring)
    'MsgBox onlynumbers
    onlynumbers = Mid(onlynumbers, InStr(1, onlynumbers, "27"), 11) & "V"
    'MsgBox onlynumbers
    If Len(onlynumbers) < 12 Then
        cleartext = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
    cleartext = onlynumbers
End Function
Function OnlyNums(sWord As String) As String
    Dim sChar As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim sTemp As String

    sTemp = ""
    For x = 1 To Len(sWord)
        sChar = Mid(sWord, x, 1)
        If Asc(sChar) >= 48 And _
          Asc(sChar) <= 57 Then
            sTemp = sTemp & sChar
        End If
    Next
    OnlyNums = sTemp
End Function
```